# Overlay handwriting map on google map

Tags: html, google-maps

I am trying to make the original map which contains the roads that doesn't written google map for mobile devices.

[image]

In other words I want to mix my original hand writing map with google map function(like GPS , pin function or popup information etc)

Is there a good solution or sample for this purpose??

Or I should integrate GPS and popup function by myself??

Comment: Seems unlikely that your image will match reality in any way.  You could certainly represent those "roads" on the "real" google maps tiles with polylines.

Comment: Your suggestion is also right, I figure out the way to overlay the images thanks to @caisEdge though , I will use polylines as you told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this adding an overlay to google maps [this way](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple)

The sample is from google maps docs

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
>     <meta charset="utf-8">
>     <title>Adding a Custom Overlay</title>
>     <style>
>       html, body {
>         height: 100%;
>         margin: 0;
>         padding: 0;
>       }
>       #map {
>         height: 100%;
>       }
>     </style>
>     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&signed_in=true"></script>
>     <script>
> // [START region_initialization]
> // This example creates a custom overlay called USGSOverlay, containing
> // a U.S. Geological Survey (USGS) image of the relevant area on the map.
>
> // Set the custom overlay object's prototype to a new instance
> // of OverlayView. In effect, this will subclass the overlay class therefore
> // it's simpler to load the API synchronously, using
> // google.maps.event.addDomListener().
> // Note that we set the prototype to an instance, rather than the
> // parent class itself, because we do not wish to modify the parent class.
>
> var overlay;
> USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
>
> // Initialize the map and the custom overlay.
>
> function initMap() {
>   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
>     zoom: 11,
>     center: {lat: 62.323907, lng: -150.109291},
>     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
>   });
>
>   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
>       new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132),
>       new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608));
>
>   // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
>   var srcImage = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/' +
>       'javascript/examples/full/images/talkeetna.png';
>
>   // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
>   // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
>   overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
> }
> // [END region_initialization]
>
> // [START region_constructor]
> /** @constructor */
> function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {
>
>   // Initialize all properties.
>   this.bounds_ = bounds;
>   this.image_ = image;
>   this.map_ = map;
>
>   // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
>   // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
>   // method so we'll leave it null for now.
>   this.div_ = null;
>
>   // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
>   this.setMap(map);
> }
> // [END region_constructor]
>
> // [START region_attachment]
> /**
>  * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
>  * added to the map.
>  */
> USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
>
>   var div = document.createElement('div');
>   div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
>   div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
>   div.style.position = 'absolute';
>
>   // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
>   var img = document.createElement('img');
>   img.src = this.image_;
>   img.style.width = '100%';
>   img.style.height = '100%';
>   img.style.position = 'absolute';
>   div.appendChild(img);
>
>   this.div_ = div;
>
>   // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
>   var panes = this.getPanes();
>   panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
> };
> // [END region_attachment]
>
> // [START region_drawing]
> USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
>
>   // We use the south-west and north-east
>   // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
>   // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
>   var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
>
>   // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
>   // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
>   // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
>   var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
>   var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
>
>   // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
>   var div = this.div_;
>   div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
>   div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
>   div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
>   div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
> };
> // [END region_drawing]
>
> // [START region_removal]
> // The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
> // we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
> USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
>   this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
>   this.div_ = null;
> };
> // [END region_removal]
>
> google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
>
>     </script>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <div id="map"></div>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```